# Box Model position and flow on menu (position absolute)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu and i'm stuck.
I want to know if someone have some idea without make too much black magic (js and stuff).

Here is my CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.wrap {
    background: red;
}
.ul-one {
    background: green;
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ul-two {
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="ul-one">
        <li>um</li>
        <li>dois</li>
        <li>tres</li>
        <li>quatro</li>
        <li>
            <ul class="ul-two">
                <li>__um</li>
                <li>__dois</li>
                <li>__tres</li>
                <li>__quatro</li>
                <li>__cinco</li>
                <li>__seis</li>
                <li>__sete</li>
                <li>__oito</li>
                <li>__nove</li>
                <li>__dez</li>
                <li>__once</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4m5g09Lb/

I want the parent (red div) grow with the children ul.
I'm reading on the web a lot and found some solution, but none of them work when use with position absolute.
This structure will be inside more divs, but i think if work for some levels, it will work with a lot of levels.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using position absolute will take the menu out of the flow so it won't affect the size of the parent(s). Another layout method would be required.

Comment: thanks for the nice edit @michael-zucchetta i read a lot of stack but i'm still learning to use it

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
ul:nth-child(even){
}
```

for all even children

```
ul:nth-child(odd){
}
```

for all odd children.